# Why does this program crash, if SPLIT is between 4 and 7

Tags: c, crash, dynamic-memory-allocation

I had a task and the program is working, for the most part, however, it crashes if I put SPLIT value between 4 and 7 (crashes at different values, if I change SIZE, but for sake of simplicity, let's keep it at 10).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<string.h>

#define SIZE 10
#define SPLIT 4
#define LOW 0
#define HIGH 10

void generateArray(int data[],int size,int low, int high){
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i=0;i<size;++i){
        data[i]=rand()%(high-low+1)+low;
    }
}

int splitData(int arraySize, int startArray[], int splitPoint, int **firstNewArray, int **secondNewArray){
    if(arraySize < 1){
        return -1;
    }
    if(splitPoint < 1 || (splitPoint >= arraySize)){
        return -1;
    }
    if(*firstNewArray != NULL || *secondNewArray != NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    *firstNewArray = malloc(splitPoint * sizeof(int));
    *secondNewArray = malloc((arraySize - splitPoint) * sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
        if(i < splitPoint){
                (*firstNewArray)[i] = startArray[i];
                printf("%d\n",startArray[i]);
        }else{
                (*secondNewArray)[i] = startArray[i];
                printf("%d\n",startArray[i]);
     }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int arraySize = SIZE ;
    int *startArray = malloc(arraySize * sizeof(int));
    generateArray(startArray,arraySize,LOW,HIGH);
    int splitPoint = SPLIT;
    int *firstNewArray = NULL;
    int *secondNewArray = NULL;
    int result;
    result = splitData(arraySize, startArray, splitPoint, &firstNewArray, &secondNewArray);
    if(result == 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
            if(i < splitPoint){
                printf("First array number %d is %d\n",i+1,firstNewArray[i]);
            }else{
                printf("Second array number %d is %d\n",i,secondNewArray[i]);
            }
        }
        free(firstNewArray);
        free(secondNewArray);
    }

    free(startArray);
    return 0;
}
```

What could be the cause of this behavior and how could I fix it? The task is to split `startArray` by the value SPLIT into 2 new dynamic arrays, that would be created in a function `splitData` and both of them could be used outside the function.

Comment: 0th) turn on and mind your compier warnings.

Comment: you are not checking `startArray` after `malloc`, it will avoid future problems

Comment: I didn't get any crash even when SPLIT is between 4 and 7.

Comment: @dspr https://prnt.sc/vj2e9r That's what I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a hard look at the marked line below

```
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
    if(i < splitPoint){
            (*firstNewArray)[i] = startArray[i];
            printf("%d\n",startArray[i]);
    }else{
            (*secondNewArray)[i] = startArray[i]; // LOOK HERE
            printf("%d\n",startArray[i]);
 }
```

Assuming an array size of 10 and a split point of 4, then `*secondNewArray` is indexed from 0 to 5; however, you’re trying to assign elements 4 through 9, which is outside the bounds of the array, leading to *undefined behavior*.  You need to adjust the value of `i` in order to map properly:

```
(*secondNewArray)[i - splitPoint] = startArray[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues with your code

1. first when you display the results:

   ```
     for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
        if(i < splitPoint){
            printf("First array number %d is %d\n",i+1,firstNewArray[i]);
        }else{
            printf("Second array number %d is %d\n",i,secondNewArray[i]);
        }
    }
   ```

This will not work specialy if array size is too higth or too low, example splitPoint is 9, this means secondNewArray Size is 1 but in this loop you are accessing `secondNewArray[9]` where it should be 0, you need to change the loop into something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < splitPoint; ++i){
  printf("First array number %d is %d\n",i+1,firstNewArray[i]);
}
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE - splitPoint; ++i){
  printf("Second array number %d is %d\n",i+splitPoint+1 ,secondNewArray[i]);
}
```

2. You have the same isssue in your split function:

   ```
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
      if(i < splitPoint){
         (*firstNewArray)[i] = startArray[i];
         printf("%d\n",startArray[i]);
      }else{
         (*secondNewArray)[i] = startArray[i];
         printf("%d\n",startArray[i]);
      }
    }
   ```

In this case also you are accessing regions outside the size of your array, let say split is 9 you will be accessing `secondNewArray[9] = startArray[9]` where it should be `secondNewArray[0] = startArray[9]`, to fix this you need to do the same thing here where you use different index for each array, the code should look like this:

```
int j = 0;
int k = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i){
  if(i < splitPoint) {
    (*firstNewArray)[j] = startArray[i];
    printf("%d\n",startArray[i]);
    j++;
  }
  else {
    (*secondNewArray)[k] = startArray[i];
    printf("%d\n",startArray[i]);
    k++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue, but why it worked with some splitPoint values in the first place?

Comment: it worked because for some reason when you did this (*secondNewArray)[i] = startArray[i];, you where writing to "not important" memory zone, with split value high, you are very far from where you reserved your memroy and you endup writing where you shouldn't, wich means it will run sometims and sometimes not, with hight split number you will have hight chances of writing/reading from wrong place (espacialy writing to wrong places), with low number, you will have low chances (5 is the lowst, 1  and 9 are higthest) since you will be off just one or two adresses